# Determining if a datetime has passed PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

**Goal**: determine if ten minutes has passed or not
**Setup**: MySQL database has a field called codeExpireDate which is a datetime field.  codeExpireDate is updated when a user performs an action on my site.  The logic below then should ideally calculate if 10 minutes has passed or not.

I see in my db that the codeExpireDate is indeed changing each time the action is performed so it is not a matter of the time never updating and it seems to be the logic part of determining if the amount of time has passed or not.  Weirdly enough the code used to work just fine before moving its location from file to file but nothing else has changed..?

I have the following bit of code (all help is **greatly appreciated**):

in recover.php:

```
//fun code stuff before this line..
$resetSQL = "UPDATE users SET tempCode = '".$rand."', codeExpireDate = sysdate() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE WHERE email = '".$email."'";
//some more magical code after this line..
```

In reset.php:

```
 //....
$timeSQL = "SELECT codeExpireDate, sysdate() currTime, tempCode FROM users WHERE token = '".$token."'";
$timeResult = mysqli_query($db,$timeSQL);
$timeRow = $timeResult->fetch_assoc();
$codeExpireDate = $timeRow["codeExpireDate"];
$currTime = $timeRow["currTime"];
$tempCodeFromDB = $timeRow["tempCode"];

$currDateTime = new DateTime($currTime);
$expireDateTime = new DateTime($codeExpireDate);

if ($currDateTime > $expireDateTime){
    echo "<script> alert('It has been longer than 10 minutes since you requested to reset your password and your code has expired.  Please request to reset it again.'); 
                   window.location='recover.php';
        </script>";
} else {
 ....
```

Comment: 10 minutes to recover a password is (*in my opinion*) very little. What is the type of the `codeExpireDate` column? Although, why not do it strictly in SQL? Then it's just another WHERE condition, and you save all those lines of PHP calculating it.

Comment: it is a datetime field - not opposed to doing it in SQL

Comment: How would the logic be? To me, it is an IF statement returning a true false but unsure of how to do that in sql.